# Registry value for specific key

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have seen many answers to this general question but not sure how to incorporate the solutions to my batch... Can you help? I need the decimal value for this command/key:

```
reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9 /v ClientID
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9 /v
 ClientID') do (set /a num = %%a)
echo/%num%
```

It will convert `0x.....` to a decimal value.
Don't forget to use `%a` instead of `%%a` if you are using cmd and not a batch file.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This worked a great treat. I have made some changes. Here's my new batch for your working answer satisfaction.

@Echo OFF
SET /p name= What's the computername to find TeamViewer ID? 
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('reg query \\%name%\HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9 /v ClientID') do (set /a ID = %%a)
Echo.
Echo.
echo Teamviewer ID for user is: %ID%
pause


Not sure how to show this as the batch data? sorry

Comment: what is the tokens=3 used for?

Comment: @serup It's used get the third delimited item.
e.g.:  `for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('echo/a b c d e') do (echo/%%a)` would echo out "c"

Answer (score 3):

Pipe the output to a file. Read each line of that file looking for the value name. Then, run the integral value through `SET /A` to convert it to decimal. This works for integral registry data types, but not if the value gets stored as `REG_BINARY` (which sometimes happens).

```
SETLOCAL

SET "KEY=HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9"
SET "VALUE=ClientID"

SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\REG_QUERY_%RANDOM%.txt"

REG QUERY "%KEY%" /v "%VALUE%" > "%TEMPFILE%"

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%k IN (%TEMPFILE%) DO (
    IF "%%~k"=="%VALUE%" (
        SET /A DATA=%%m
    )
)
DEL /Q "%TEMPFILE%"

@ECHO Data: %DATA%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution from Rafael works peachy though I am sure this one works also. Very helpful!